# Dataframe to Series of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'col1':[5,'',2], 'col2':['','',1], 'col3':[9,'','']})  
print(df)

col1 col2 col3
       5    9
 1               
 2     2    1
```

Is there a simple way to turn it into a `pd.Series` of lists, avoiding empty elements? So:

```
0 [5,9]
1 [1]
2 [2,2,1]
```

Comment: but why would you want to?

Comment: I need it for a rather specific task. And was wondering if there is a say opposite way of doing `.apply(pd.Series)`, @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with remove empty value:

```
L = [x[x != ''].tolist() for i, x in df.T.items()]
s = pd.Series(L, index=df.index)
```

Or convert values to lists by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `split`:

```
L = df.to_dict(orient='split')['data']
print (L)
[[5, '', 9], ['', '', ''], [2, 1, '']]
```

And then remove empty values:

```
s = pd.Series([[y for y in x if y != ''] for x in L], index=df.index)

print (s)
0    [5, 9]
1        []
2    [2, 1]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [df.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

Just take `df.values`. Convert them into list and remove empty elements using `map`:

```
In [2193]: df
Out[2193]: 
  col1 col2 col3
0         5    9
1    1          
2    2    2    1
```

#### One-liner:

```
In [2186]: pd.Series(df.values.tolist()).map(lambda row: [x for x in row if x != ''])
Out[2186]: 
0       [5, 9]
1          [1]
2    [2, 2, 1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution

Answer (score 2):

Can be done as follows:

```
# Break down into list of tuples
records = df.to_records().tolist()

# Convert tuples into lists
series = pd.Series(records).map(list)

# Get rid of empty strings
series.map(lambda row: list(filter(lambda x: x != '', row)))

# ... alternatively
series.map(lambda row: [x for x in row if x != ''])
```

resulting in

```
0    [0, 5, 9]
1          [1]
2    [2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This is not getting rid of the empty elements though

Comment: remove 0 values also :(

Comment: OK, hacked my way through at the expense of gracefulness.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
In[1]: [x[x.apply(lambda k: k != '')].tolist() for i, x in df.iterrows()]

Out[1]: [[5, 9], [], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks @caiobelfort

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@jezreal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704735/9209546). But if you do not expect `0` values, you can use the inherent `False`-ness of empty strings:

```
L = [x[x.astype(bool)].tolist() for i, x in df.T.items()]
res = pd.Series(L, index=df.index)
```

Comment: if no `0` in values then solution working, I agree. So not usable for general data, unfortunately...

Comment: @jezrael, Sure. If `0` data is not expected, this solution is around 1.5x more efficient for large datasets vs comparison with empty string. So for edge cases, and future visitors, it's worth noting.

Comment: There could be '0's also in this case. Thx anyway, and agree that it could be useful in other cases